# Label is not visible on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib

I am trying following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5], label="Line1", linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

However label is not getting printed for shown line.

What is wrong with above code ?

Answer (score 2):

The `plt.plot` `label` keyword argument is not for automatically creating labels on the graphs. They just mean "call (a.k.a. label) this object by this name so when I make a legend you can put that name in the legend instead of line0x72728124172"

If you want it to show the label just call `plt.legend()` before `plt.plot()`.